# CSS pseudo-class :required does not work together with pseudo-element ::before

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

My intent is to put a * on labels of required fields.

I am testing with Chrome 47, Firefox 43 and Opera 34.
None of these can understand the CSS selector

```
span:required::before
```

According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation they all should be able to understand it, and if you use

```
span:hover::before
```

instead, it actually works.
What do I do wrong?
Here is my Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      span::before {
        content: "\00A0";
      }
      span:required::before { /* This does NOT work! */
        content: "*";
      }
      span:hover::before { /* But this DOES work! */
        content: "_";
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <form>
      <p>
        <span required>Name</span>
        <input id="name" type="text" />
      </p>
      
      <p>
        <span>Date of Birth</span>
        <input id="birth" type="text" />
      </p>
    </form>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've never seen `required` attribute added on `span` element and while it may work for you, shouldn't you be putting it on the `input` instead? That is the intended use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

- Form labels have a dedicated element, `label`. You should be using that, not `span`.
- The `required` attribute only applies to the controls themselves, that is, `input`, `select`, `textarea`, etc. A `span` is just plain text (and a label is *basically* that on its own) and the `required` attribute makes no sense on such an element.<sup>1</sup>

If you're trying to style a label of a required input, you will need to give it a class name instead.

This has nothing to do with `:required::before`, though, given that most form elements are replaced elements, it's unlikely you'll find that pseudo-class and that pseudo-element together.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>`contenteditable` notwithstanding.</sub>

Comment: OK, the HTML spec says that "required" is just for input elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute

Answer (score 0):

The `required` attribute must be in the form control, and you should use `label`s instead of `span`s.

Then, you can use the selector `:required + label::before`. To make it work the form control must appear before the label in the DOM order, but then you can use floats or flexbox to rearrange.

```css
p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
label {
  float: left;
}
label::before {
  content: "\00A0";
  font-family: monospace;
}
:required + label::before {
  content: "*";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <input id="name" type="text" required />
    <label for="name">Name</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="birth" type="text" />
    <label for="birth">Date of Birth</label>
  </p>
</form>
```